# UPDATE SQL query showing success but nothing updates in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the following php code that updates the sql table with the edited data that is posted from the form:

```
$user_input_id = $_POST['id'];
$user_input_abc = $_POST['abc'];
$user_input_def = $_POST['def'];
$user_input_xyz = $_POST['xyz'];

$sqlTable = 'abc_table';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE $sqlTable SET abc=?, def=?, xyz=? WHERE id=?");
$rc = $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $user_input_abc, $user_input_def, $user_input_xyz, $user_input_id);

$stmt->execute();

echo 'Your information was updated to the database.';

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

When I edit the form and submit the change, the php page with the above script shows that "Your information was updated to the database." but when I check the database, the edits are not updated and its still showing the old data.

I also tried echoing the variables like `echo $user_input_id, $user_input_abc, $user_input_def, $user_input_xyz;` to make sure the variables do have the edited texts that is posted from the from in the previous page and they seem right. Its just that the update query that is supposedly showing successful is not updating the edited texts in my sql table.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't see a commit in your code.

Comment: committed transaction ? or auto commit enabled?

Comment: Sorry... I dont know. This is my first UPDATE query I am learning. Would you be able to give me an example please?

Comment: `xyz=?,` a comma too much maybe? Wonder it shows success however. Oh well, seems to just always show success :p

Comment: @Jonny 5: Sorry, the comma was a typo in this sample code. But my actual code I am testing doesnt have the comma and it still doesnt update the db. I dont about commit transaction. I wrote the above code looking at a tutorial example and it didint mention anything about commit. How do I do that?

Comment: are you sure that the ID exist in the DB?, please verify your connections settings too

Comment: You don't have any error checking.  `if (!$stmt) echo $mysqli->error;` right after `prepare()`.  Also `if (!$rc)` same thing after `bind_param()`. As is, the code has no way of knowing it didn't actually make an insertion and just passes on to the `echo`.

Comment: @ jcho360: I think you might be on to something. I just tried `echo $user_input_id;` in that page, and it was empty. I will look at the previous page codes and will report back.

Comment: @jcho360. Found it. It was a stupid typo from my end. I will post the details as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the `$_POST['id']` that was causing the problem for me. The previous form page that passes the ID to this update.php file had `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $id ?>" />` instead of `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />`. I missed the `php` after `<?`. Because of that, the ID that was posted was empty. I did have error checking for `prepare() failed`, `bind_param() failed` and `execute() failed` (although I only showed the brief code above without the error checking lines), it still didint show any errors and the query was showing as successful. This is caused due to empty id field, so the query was successful and didint show any errors but since the id was empty no rows in table was updated. Once I made sure that the id is posted correctly, everything else worked.  (Silly mistake caused me a headache)

Thank you all for your input that helped me in noticing my mistake.